# How to use oracle logminer in python?

Tags: python, oracle

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import cx_Oracle
```

I want to use `dbms_logmnr_d.build()` in Python, but following error occurs:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "test.py", line 10, in
>
> ```
> x=c.callproc("EXECUTE dbms_logmnr_d.build(dictionary_filename => 'dictionary.ora', 
>                 dictionary_location =>'/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/LOGMNR')")
> ```
>
> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError:
>   ORA-06550: Line 1, column 15:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol `DBMS_LOGMNR_D` when expecting one of the following:
>    `: = . ( @ % ; immediate`
>   The symbol `: =` was substituted for `DBMS_LOGMNR_D` to continue.

---

#### Example:

```
conn=cx_Oracle.connect('example/pass@localhost/XE')
c=conn.cursor()                                         
x=c.callproc("EXECUTE dbms_logmnr_d.build(dictionary_filename => 'dictionary.ora', dictionary_location =>'/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/LOGMNR')")
conn.commit();                  
c.close()                                                 
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the `execute` keyword, and pass arguments separately:

```
c.callproc("dbms_logmnr_d.build", keywordParameters = dict(dictionary_filename = "dictionary.ora", dictionary_location = "/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/LOGMNR"))
```